# python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

По запросу:

```
print(soup.find('div', 'b-comment__user'))
```

выдает такой результат

```
<div class="b-comment__user">
<a href="http://pikabu.ru/profile/EndlessSpace"><span class="">EndlessSpace</span></a>
<span>отправлено</span>
<time class="b-comment__time" datetime="1347413239">1215 дней назад</time>
</div>
```

а какая должна быть команда, чтобы выдала только: `EndlessSpace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом `.select`. Он позволяет искать элементы при помощи CSS-селекторов

```
print([e.string for e in soup.select("div.b-comment__user a span")])
```

Comment: спасибо, даже не думал про .select!